# Implementing a download button in jhipster

Tags: angular, jhipster

I'm trying to implement a simple download button in jhipster monolithic application that will help me download all the entries of a particular entity.

Can someone help me and tell me how to go about it?

Comment: Angular framework. When we create instances of entities, I want an option to be able to download all those entries. I created a new button. I'm not sure how to map it to a method that will implement a query that will fetch all the entries. How do I have to do it?

Comment: See how query method in your entity service is called from entity component: https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/blob/master/src/main/webapp/app/entities/label/label.service.ts#L30-L33 and https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/blob/master/src/main/webapp/app/entities/label/label.service.ts#L30-L33  This is pure Angular, nothing specific to JHipster. If you a need a detailed answer, please edit your question and paste your button code. Also clarify what you mean by "download".

Answer (score 1):

Add this packages :

```
yarn add file-saver
yarn add xlsx
```

Then create this service :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver';
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';

const EXCEL_TYPE = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=UTF-8';
const EXCEL_EXTENSION = '.xlsx';

@Injectable()
export class ExcelService {

  constructor() { }

public exportAsExcelFile(json: any[], excelFileName: string): void {
    const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(json);
    excelFileName = this.convertToSlug(excelFileName);

    const range = XLSX.utils.decode_range(worksheet['!ref']);
    for (let C = range.s.r; C <= range.e.r; ++C) {
        const address = XLSX.utils.encode_col(C) + '1'; // <-- first row, column number C
        if (!worksheet[address]) { continue; }
        worksheet[address].v = worksheet[address].v.toUpperCase();
    }

    const workbook: XLSX.WorkBook = { Sheets: { 'data': worksheet }, SheetNames: ['data'] };
    // const excelBuffer: any = XLSX.write(workbook, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'buffer' });
    const excelBuffer: any = XLSX.write(workbook, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'array' });

    this.saveAsExcelFile(excelBuffer, excelFileName);
}

private saveAsExcelFile(buffer: any, fileName: string): void {
    const data: Blob = new Blob([buffer], {
        type: EXCEL_TYPE
    });
    const date =  new Date();

    FileSaver.saveAs(data, fileName + '_export_' + this.dateToYMD(date) + '_' + date.getTime() + EXCEL_EXTENSION);
}

dateToYMD(date: Date) {
    const d = date.getDate();
    const m = date.getMonth() + 1; // Month from 0 to 11
    const y = date.getFullYear();
    return '' + y + '-' + (m <= 9 ? '0' + m : m) + '-' + (d <= 9 ? '0' + d : d);
}

convertToSlug(Text) {
    return Text
        .toLowerCase()
        .replace(/ /g, '-')
        .replace(/[^\w-]+/g, '')
        ;
}
}
```

For the usage :

```
 entities: IEntities[];
  this.excelService.exportAsExcelFile(entities, 'download');
```